# Guaranteeing non-reuse of IDENTITY keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, key, identity, uniqueidentifier

My table, *Item* is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Item
(
ItemID      INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
OtherData   INT NOT NULL,
)
```

I need to be sure that once an *ItemID* is generated, that same *ItemID* will never be generated again, even if rows are removed from this table.

Does IDENTITY guarantee this property? If not, how can I guarantee this in the easiest way possible?

SQL Server 2008 R2

edit: According to comments, if *IDENTITY_INSERT* is off AND re-seeding does not occur than I can be guaranteed that an Identity is not re-used. Is there any way to disallow *IDENTITY_INSERT ON* on a table? And prevent re-seeding?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx : Take a look at the remarks section : "The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following: Uniqueness of the value" -> "Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index."

Comment: @Cuonic actually it means that you can insert two same values with `identiy_insert on` or with replication. But sql-server will always generate greater value than previously generated.

Comment: As long as you don't do any reseeding ("resetting") on your identity, then this is guaranteed. If you leave your identity column alone, it will never create an already used identity value again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UNIQUE constraint on the key column - and instead of deleting a row, add a "deleted" Boolean column (ie a column in which you record that a record is deleted). To be sure that a value is not reused you must keep a record of it...

Answer (score 0):

Re: [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx):

> User must own the table or have ALTER permission on the table.

If your users have that much power, there's not much you can do. If they don't (which I expect) you don't need to "disallow" it.

Similarly, re-seeding a table (or truncating it, another thing that will restart the numbering) is only allowed by certain users who, if they can perform **these** actions, can almost certainly bypass anything else you might try to do.

Your *ordinary* users will not be able to cause identity values to be reused. So, your concerns are generally unfounded. Just use the `IDENTITY` property.